# Test Cases are getting passed but not able to get logs file in logs folder

Tags: python, testing, logging, automation, pytest

[image]

[image]

I have created a customLogger.py file to capture logs and entered location.
then i ran test_login.py file of test cases where i used logs method.

Is there any problem with the log location that i added.
Test Cases are getting passed but not getting automation.log inside Logs folder

I was expecting automation.log file to be created inside logs folder after successfully running of the test cases.

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post all code, input, output, and errors as plain text only.